# How to plot non-continuous custom date format in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've a column with custom date format: `YYYYWeekNo` e.g. 201801, 201802...201851, 201852

The problem arises when I have data that jumps from 201752 to 201801 which creates the plot to treat the data as continuous of 100 scale, hence the graph is distorted

Is there a way I can resolve this plot with non-continuous `x` label?

```
x = []
year = 2017
for i in range(104):
    j = i+1
    if j <= 52:
        x.append(year * 100 + j)
    else:
        k = j - 52
        x.append(((year+1) * 100 ) + k)


np.random.seed(1)
values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=5000, size=104)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'year_week': x, 'values': values})
df.set_index('year_week').plot(figsize=(15, 5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can 'break' the axis using [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html). This would be the tailored version:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = []
year = 2017
for i in range(104):
    j = i+1
    if j <= 52:
        x.append(year * 100 + j)
    else:
        k = j - 52
        x.append(((year+1) * 100 ) + k)
np.random.seed(1)
values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=5000, size=104)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'year_week': x, 'values': values})

f,(ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True, facecolor='w', figsize=(10,10))

# plot the same data on both axes
ax.plot(df['year_week'], df['values'])
ax2.plot(df['year_week'], df['values'])

ax.set_xlim(201700,201753)
ax2.set_xlim(201800,201853)

# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.tick_params()
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()

#this gets rid of scientific notation, so it's more readable
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
ax2.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

What's more, is seems like there's a package dedicated to this particular problem:

[Brokenaxes](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes)